# Open a PowerPoint file contained in a JAR file

Tags: java, resources

One of my resource files is a PowerPoint presentation and I want to open the presentation with PowerPoint. If I run the code in Eclipse everything works fine but if I run the executable .jar with `java -jar jarname.jar`, PowerPoint says it can not read the file.

Is it possible to read packed resource files? Or is only the executing jar able to read these files? If so what would you do? Write the file in a temp folder?

Absolute path to presentation if I run in eclipse:

`C:\Users\RPR\workspace\CommandLineExecuter\bin\blaa.pptx`

Absolute path to presentation if I run the executable jar:

`C:\Users\RPR\workspace\CommandLineExecuter\file:\C:\Users\RPR\workspace\CommandLineExecuter\CommandLineExecuter.jar!\blaa.pptx`

PowerPoint is not able to read the file even if I hardcode the path to `C:\Users\RPR\workspace\CommandLineExecuter\CommandLineExecuter.jar!\blaa.pptx`

Code where I load the resource:

```
File presentation = new File(CommandLineExecuter.class.getResource(
        "/blaa.pptx").getFile());

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",
        "cd & \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\POWERPNT.exe\ "
                + presentation.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Show us the code where you load this resource.

Comment: getResource().getFile() doesn't do what you think it does. The OS has no idea how to adress into the jar file. And for simply opening a document, let the OS handle it. Take a look at the Desktop.open() method.

Comment: The problem is I have to open it via commandline because I have to add some parameters to PowerPoint. I run ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\POWERPNT.exe" /M "blaa.pptx" "CreateVideo720p") to automatically start a makro.

Comment: When you run in Eclipse, your CLASSPATH points to your bin/ folder, so that file really does exist on the filesystem and PP can resolve it. Once packaged in a JAR, it no longer resolves to a single file on the filesystem. If you want to package it with the JAR, you'll want to write the resource to a tmp file to open it in PP, or find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), then you can extract the file from your JAR and place it somewhere that PowerPoint can access.

For instance, [create a temporary file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#creating) and use [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html) to copy the data to a `FileOutputStream` pointing at your temporary file.

Finally, pass this temporary file path to PowerPoint.

Comment: Okai thank you. So I have to create a temp file and it is not possible to access the resource files from another program except my jar?

Comment: PowerPoint certainly won't be able to open a file within a JAR.